# simple exercise of euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry

I've to solve this simple exercise but i can't see how.
Problem: let $AB$ and $CD$ two equivalent ropes of one circle of centre $O$. Let $P$ and $Q$ two points that belong on the extentions of the previous ropes such that $BP$ and $DQ$ are equivalent. So show that the centre $O$ belong on the axis of the segment $PQ$ .
[image: rope of a circle]

Comment: What is a "rope of a circle"?  Can you provide a drawing?  Even a snapshot of a hand drawing, with the points labelled, would suffice.

Comment: @Brian Tung in the figure you can see the rope of a circle. I don't know the right english term

Comment: Ahh, OK, they're called "chords."

Comment: By "axis," do you mean "perpendicular bisector"?  That is, the line that is perpendicular to $\overline{PQ}$ and intersects it at its midpoint?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: @Brian Tung how you that $P$ and $Q$ lie in the same circle?

Comment: @Brian Tung  sorry i get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, show that $OP = OQ$; that is, both $P$ and $Q$ lie on a circle with center $O$:

- $OB = OD$ (both on the same circle)
- $BP = DQ$ (given)
- $\triangle OAB \cong \triangle OCD$ (side-side-side, see below)

  - $OA = OC$ (both on the same circle)
  - $OB = OD$ (both on the same circle)
  - $AB = CD$ (given)
- $m\angle OBA = m\angle ODC$ (corresponding angles of congruent triangles)
- $m\angle OBP = m\angle ODQ$ (supplementary angles of equal angles)
- $\triangle OBP = \triangle ODQ$ (side-angle-side)
- $OP = OQ$ (corresponding sides of congruent triangles)

Now consider triangle $OPQ$.  Let $R$ be the midpoint of $PQ$.  Then

- $PR = QR$ (midpoint)
- $OP = OQ$ (proved above)
- $\triangle OPQ$ is isosceles
- $m\angle OPQ = m\angle OQP$ (base angles of isosceles triangle)
- $\triangle OPR \cong \triangle OQR$ (side-angle-side)
- $m\angle ORP = m\angle ORQ$ (corresponding angles of congruent triangles)
- $m\angle ORP = m\angle ORQ = 90$ (congruent supplementary angles)

Therefore $\overline{OR}$ is the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{PQ}$.